# COPY failed: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, copy

I am trying to build an image by simply copying `requirement.txt` into it. My directory structure is as below:

```
- app  
    - Dockerfile  
    - requirement.txt
```

And my dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY requirements.txt /home/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

I am ensuring that the `requirement.txt` file is inside docker build context and there is no `.dockerignore` file which could be possibly ignoring this file. But yet I am getting this below error.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> 11c6e5fd966a
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /home/app
 ---> Running in 5ea181f45c01
Removing intermediate container 5ea181f45c01
 ---> c150cd1dea37
Step 3/4 : COPY requirements.txt /home/app/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder580673490/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

Command used for building the image : `docker build -t test_app:0.1 .`

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Your file listing shows `requirement.txt`, without an `s`; does the file name on disk match what you `COPY` in the Dockerfile?  (The pip requirements file is typically `requirements.txt` with an `s`, but nothing enforces that name.)

Comment: @DavidMaze  You are right. How did I miss that? Renaming `requirement.txt` file to `requirements.txt` (with `s`) solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`WORKDIR` switches working directory in docker image, but not in host.

```
COPY app/requirements.txt /home/app/
```

It works correctly.